# statemodifier halt() not working

Tags: famo.us

Following Famo.us University Animation part. The following code didn't halt the translation, instead runs straight to the end. I expected it halted where it is clicked. Am I right?

```
surface.on('click', function() {
  stateModifier.halt();
  surface.setContent('halted');
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is: **It will halt the transform, but will complete at the transforms final position**

That is why you see the jump from where it is clicked.

Rather than halt the Transform just set the transform to the current Transform position.

**[Example jsBin](http://jsbin.com/rababo/1/edit?js,output)**

```js
  surface.on('click', function() {
    //stateModifier.halt();
    stateModifier.setTransform(stateModifier.getTransform());
    surface.setContent('Halted');
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Interestingly the document of StateModifier says halt(): stop the transition. But transition dump to the final stage instead, which I didn't expected. I really don't like much of the Famo.us' documentation per se.